# How do I install jdownloader?

Tags: software-installation, jdownloader

I want to install using a script

but the problem I don't know how to using this method to get a install.

Try out our new Install/Start-Script for Linux/Mac!
wget must be installed on system!
Download jd.sh
chmod +x jd.sh
start jd.sh
Note: Open jd.sh to read Manual or change Settings!

please teach me and give me a detail to get the jdownloader install.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To install jdownloader try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jd-team/jdownloader

sudo apt-get update

 sudo apt-get install jdownloader-installer
```

Comment: just an observation:
the 1st command (under Ubuntu 16.04) churns out information by the jd-team that the 3rd line shall be `sudo apt-get install jdownloader-installer`  ( the accepted answer does not have the last `-installer`)

Answer (score 5):

To use the script without installing:

wget http://installer.jdownloader.org/jd_unix_0_9.sh

```
chmod +x jd_unix_0.9.sh

./jd_unix_0.9.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

For devices including Linux operating System you can install the downloading tool JDOWNLOADER by following these steps:

1. Open the Ubuntu Software Center
2. Go to Main Menu\Edit\Software Sources
3. Go to the second tab Titled Other Sources
4. Add New Software source:

   - **deb** http://ppa.launchpad.net/jd-team/jdownloader/ubuntu
   - **deb-src** http://ppa.launchpad.net/jd-team/jdownloader/ubuntu
5. go to the search bar and you'll find yours.