# Is safe to install JDownloader on Ubuntu?

Tags: security, 17.04, malware, jdownloader

I read [Do not install Jdownloader](https://www.reddit.com/r/software/comments/3i3km9/do_not_install_jdownloader_2_as_it_installs/) and people say that JD2 has a malware. But in that topic talk about Windows.

Should I be worry about it? Or JDownloader 2 can't infect my Ubuntu? If i install following [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162058/how-do-i-install-jdownloader), can I to be safe from malware?  Else I saw that [this site](http://jdownloader.org/jdownloader2)  and says Adware-free. Where do I should install JD2 to be safe?

Comment: The thread is about Windows only and no longer relevant. I recently installed it in Windows 10 and had the chance to opt-out of all the sponsored crap.

Answer (score 2):

JDownloader is an opensource software, means you can inspect its source code to see whatever its infected or not.

However when you are installing it from a third party PPA, that means you have to trust the owner of that repository, because what you will download and install is already compile and packaged binary files which there is no way we can tell what it's going to do on your PC.

If the main program is some kind of malware so there is nothing you can do about it, if you install it you'll get infected.

Adware is some kind of software which show you advertise or changes and install some other advertising software on your system, Adware-free means it's not that kind of program.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i'll install from ppa, it is reliabl becuse in that topic none says nothing about a malware.

Comment: No one said nothing because no one can tell from a binary ... :-) As I said it's up to you to decide.

Comment: I would still say that a source that many people use/trust should be "more safe" than just downloading it from somewhere on the net ... Some people will at least control network traffic coming from that program or find dubious actions.